# JSF 2. Dynamic row generation and binding fields in datatable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, commandbutton

I am new to Jsf and I am trying to create the following functionality in my Jsf application.

- Display a row with - 'From Date' - 'To Date' 'Add button' 'Remove button'
- Clicking on Add button should add a row next to it with the 2 date picker fields and the 2 buttons.
- Clicking on Remove should remove the corresponding row.
- From Date , To Date - These two fields are date pickers from prime faces. Validate the date fields such that the From Date is not after the To Date. There are other fields in the form and validation should happen on form submit and not when the Add/Remove buttons are clicked.

Following is the code that I have developed so far. Please excuse any mistakes since it is still WIP but I am totally open to any suggestions to improve the code.

```
<h:dataTable value="#{personInfo.profileForm.serviceDateList}" var="serviceDateObj" id="servideTblId">
<h:column>
    <p:calendar id="#{serviceDateObj}" binding="#{bindingVar}" value="#{serviceDateObj.fromDate}" size="10" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" readonlyInput="true" navigator="true" yearRange="1900:2050" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['msg.veteran.service.start.required']}"  valueChangeListener="#{personInfo.addDirtyFields}">
        <f:attribute name="fieldName" value="Active Duty Service Start Date"/>
    </p:calendar>
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <h:outputText value="to"/>
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <p:calendar value="#{serviceDateObj.toDate}" size="10" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd" readonlyInput="true" navigator="true" yearRange="1900:2050" required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['msg.veteran.service.end.required']}"  valueChangeListener="#{personInfo.addDirtyFields}">
        <f:validator validatorId="toDateInPastValidator" />
        <f:attribute name="errMsgNameToField" value="Active Duty Service End Date" />
        <f:attribute name="errMsgNameFromField" value="Active Duty Service Start Date" />
        <f:attribute name="fromDate" value="#{bindingVar}"/>
        <f:attribute name="fieldName" value="Active Duty Service End Date"/>
    </p:calendar>
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <h:commandButton  value="Add" rendered="#{personInfo.profileForm.serviceDateList.size() lt 5}">
        <f:ajax event="click" render="servideTblId" listener="#{personInfo.profileForm.addServiceDate}"/>                               
    </h:commandButton>
</h:column>
<h:column>
    <h:commandButton value="Remove " rendered="#{personInfo.profileForm.serviceDateList.size() ne 1}">
        <f:ajax event="click" render="servideTblId" listener="#{personInfo.profileForm.removeServiceDt(serviceDateObj)}"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:column>
```

```
public void addServiceDate(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){
++serviceDtCount;
ServiceDate sDate = new ServiceDate(null, null, serviceDtCount);
serviceDateList.add(sDate);
}

public void removeServiceDt(ServiceDate sDate){
--serviceDtCount;
if(sDate != null){
    serviceDateList.remove(sDate);
}       
}

public class ServiceDate implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 6963595158386578748L;

private Date fromDate;
private Date toDate;
private int id;

ServiceDate(){
    super();
}

ServiceDate(Date fromDate, Date toDate, int count){
    this.fromDate = fromDate;
    this.toDate = toDate;
    this.id=count;
}

public Date getFromDate() {
    return fromDate;
}
public void setFromDate(Date fromDate) {
    this.fromDate = fromDate;
}
public Date getToDate() {
    return toDate;
}
public void setToDate(Date toDate) {
    this.toDate = toDate;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

Following are the problems I have.

1. Clicking on Add/remove adds new rows and columns but the value is not getting stored in the model and the values entered gets wiped out from all fields when a row is added or removed.
2. I am clueless as to how to dynamically bind the from date into the to date validator so that I can get the from date value entered, in the validator in order to validate.

Any help in this is much appreciated.

Comment: for your first question, please make sure that your personInfo bean is not request scoped. if it still doesn't work, add `execute="servideTblId"` to f:ajax tags.

Comment: Thank you for your comments @tt_emrah.. PersonInfo is viewscoped. Adding execute didnt make any difference actually. Infact the "addServiceDate" method wasnt getting called after adding it. Am I missing something?